# Replace `exp(I*pi)` with `-1` in SymPy expression

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

When using sympy to integrate an expression often there is exp(I*pi) somewhere in the result:

```
from sympy.functions import *
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_latex=False, use_unicode=False)
shift = Symbol('shift', real=True, positive=True)
x = Symbol('x', real=True, positive=True)
p = Symbol('p', real=True)

expr = integrate(exp(-p)/(p+shift), (p, x, oo))
expr
```

```
/            /   /             I*pi\     /             I*pi\             \    
|            |log\(shift + x)*e    / - Ei\(shift + x)*e    /   EulerGamma|    
|(shift + x)*|---------------------------------------------- + ----------| - l
\            \                  shift + x                      shift + x /    

                          \       
                          |  shift
og(shift + x) - EulerGamma|*e     
                          /
```

But it is known that `exp(I*pi)` == -1. And it is inconvenient to have complex numbers in expression that intended to be real. Is it possible to replace somehow `exp(I*pi)` with -1 in expression? I have tried `simplify()` and `subs(exp(I*pi), -1)`. Neither the first nor the second helps.

Answer (score 0):

The special printing directive is hiding what you really have. It isn't `exp(I*pi)` it is `polar_exp(I*pi)`. If you `print(expr)` you will see this:

```
((shift + x)*((log((shift + x)*exp_polar(I*pi)) - Ei((shift +
x)*exp_polar(I*pi)))/(shift + x) + EulerGamma/(shift + x)) - log(shift
+ x) - EulerGamma)*exp(shift)
```

Replacing with `.subs(exp_polar(I*pi), -1)` will work...but you should read up about `polar_lift` and `exp_polar` to understand what it is telling you and what you should be aware of when making that replacement.

Comment: Could provide a link or summarize the implications of the `polar_lift`?

Comment: The [official docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy.functions.elementary.exponential.exp_polar) seem quite brief: *The main difference is that polar numbers don’t “wrap around” at 2π* and *Represent a ‘polar number’ (see g-function Sphinx documentation)* without further links.